# Java и Jsoup помогите

Tags: java, android, html, html5, jsoup

Вот мой код

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://elitedrop.ru/").userAgent("Mozilla").data("name", "jsoup").get();
    System.out.println(doc);
}
```

После отправки этого запроса к сайту мне вместо его Html кода возвращает вот это:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <script>var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();function eraseCookieFromAllPaths(name) { var pathBits = location.pathname.split("/");var pathCurrent = " path=";document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";for (var i = 0; i < pathBits.length; i++) {pathCurrent += ((pathCurrent.substr(-1) != "/") ? "/" : "") + pathBits[i];document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;" + pathCurrent + ";";}}eraseCookieFromAllPaths("BHC");xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { var a=xmlhttp.responseText;document.cookie="BHC="+a+"; path=/";document.location.href="/?name=jsoup"; } };xmlhttp.open("GET", "/banhammer/pid", true);xmlhttp.send();</script> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Объясните пожалуйста в чём проблема(с других сайтов код приходит)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сайт, откуда Вы хотите спарсить информацию, вероятнее всего, фильтрует запросы по полю User Agent.

Для работы с этим сайтом с помощью Jsoup необходимо установить валидный User Agent, например:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

Код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://elitedrop.ru/").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36").data("name", "jsoup").get();
    System.out.println(doc);
}
```

успешно выводит на консоль HTML-код заданной страницы.

Comment: он по прежнему выводит вот это

Comment: @Vadim, Странно, у меня проблема решилась установкой юзер агента. Попробуйте через прокси зайти.

Comment: Неа, по прежнему выводит тот скрипт, который я указал в своём вопросе

Comment: можете прислать код или скрин, пожалуйста

Comment: @Vadim, Код я написал в ответе, а насчет скриншота... – зачем?

Comment: можете сделать скрин или сбросить html код того что у вас вывелось в консоли?

Comment: @Vadim, На консоль у меня вывелся HTML-код страницы, ровно тот, который Вы можете получить нажав ctrl+u в браузере.

Comment: я скопировал ваш код и мне по прежнему выводит этот несчастный скрипт

Comment: @Vadim  у меня всё работает    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfDoi.png" width="100%">

Comment: @Михаил Ребров Спасибо что скинули скрин, но у меня всё равно не работает =(

Comment: @Vadim, как ответили ниже - скорее всего Вы столкнулись с защитой от роботов. Это значит, что на сервере стоит ограничение на кол-во запросов от одного клиента или на их скорость(кол-во запросов в  еденицу времени) и после преодоления этой отметки выводится проверка клиента(в Вашем случае это проверка на наличие у клиента JavaScript'а). Избежать этого можно либо используя ряд прокси(чтобы запросы шли с разных IP) либо же соблюдая "скоростной режим". Также видел кустарные способы парсинга в таких случаях с помощью Selenium'а. В нём есть JavaScript и там можно обработать действия на клиенте.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего на стороне сайта стоит защита от роботов/DDoS, которая использует тот факт, что в браузере "живого" пользователя будет выполнятся JavaScript.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а как можно обойти эту защиту?